# Ruby / Rails Gender pronouns

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How do you guys handle these?  When comparing 2 people, but using their gender specific pronouns?  "Bob likes Stacy.  He has always longed for her, and her long hair.  She doesn't like Bob, and his creepy stares..."

So, Bob is a entity in the database, and so is Stacy. `bob = User.find_by_name('Bob')` and `stacy = User.find_by_name('Stacy')`.  `bob.gender` returns male, and `stacy.gender` returns female.

The above quote would be from an entity in the database as well.  `Match.find(23).body`.  I would like to put some generic stuff in the database, and have it fillable, but it doesn't seem to work.  `@p1.first_name likes @p2.first_name.  @p1.She has always longed for @p2.her, and @p2.her_p long hair.  @p2.She doesn't like @p2.first_name, and @p2.her_p creepy stares...` Here, I have methods that take the female pronoun as the name, and return the actual.

In the controller, `@dislike = Match.find(23).body`, `@p1 = bob`, and `@p2 = stacy` right?

In the view, `<%= @dislike %>`

That will not work.  I've also looked at gsub, and stripping accordingly.  I can make it work.  I'm just curious how others have handled this situation, or if I've convoluted it immensely.

Comment: I don't quite understand what the question is. If the text is a template, make it a template, and use erb/equivalent. Otherwise you need to evaluate using string interpolation using the current context, but this looks like a templating problem so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def rend(p1, p2)
  body = self.body
  body = body.gsub(/p1.first_name/, p1.first_name)
  body = body.gsub(/p2.first_name/, p2.first_name)
  if p1.gender == 'male'
    body = body.gsub(/p1.she/, 'he')
    body = body.gsub(/p1.her_p/, 'his')
    body = body.gsub(/p1.her/, 'him')
    body = body.gsub(/p1.herself/, 'himself')
    body = body.gsub(/p1.hers/, 'his')
    body = body.gsub(/p1.She/, 'He')
    body = body.gsub(/p1.Her_p/, 'His')
    body = body.gsub(/p1.Her/, 'Him')
    body = body.gsub(/p1.Herself/, 'Himself')
    body = body.gsub(/p1.Hers/, 'His') 
  end
  if p1.gender == 'female'
    body = body.gsub(/p1.she/, 'she')
    body = body.gsub(/p1.her_p/, 'her')
    body = body.gsub(/p1.her/, 'her')
    body = body.gsub(/p1.herself/, 'herself')
    body = body.gsub(/p1.hers/, 'hers')
    body = body.gsub(/p1.She/, 'She')
    body = body.gsub(/p1.Her_p/, 'Her')
    body = body.gsub(/p1.Her/, 'Her')
    body = body.gsub(/p1.Herself/, 'Herself')
    body = body.gsub(/p1.Hers/, 'Hers')
  end
  if p2.gender == 'male'
    body = body.gsub(/p2.she/, 'he')
    body = body.gsub(/p2.her_p/, 'his')
    body = body.gsub(/p2.her/, 'him')
    body = body.gsub(/p2.herself/, 'himself')
    body = body.gsub(/p2.hers/, 'his')
    body = body.gsub(/p2.She/, 'He')
    body = body.gsub(/p2.Her_p/, 'His')
    body = body.gsub(/p2.Her/, 'Him')
    body = body.gsub(/p2.Herself/, 'Himself')
    body = body.gsub(/p2.Hers/, 'His')
  end
  if p2.gender == 'female'
    body = body.gsub(/p2.she/, 'she')
    body = body.gsub(/p2.her_p/, 'her')
    body = body.gsub(/p2.her/, 'her')
    body = body.gsub(/p2.herself/, 'herself')
    body = body.gsub(/p2.hers/, 'hers')
    body = body.gsub(/p2.She/, 'She')
    body = body.gsub(/p2.Her_p/, 'Her')
    body = body.gsub(/p2.Her/, 'Her')
    body = body.gsub(/p2.Herself/, 'Herself')
    body = body.gsub(/p2.Hers/, 'Hers')
  end

  body
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a database just add a column to the Name table for Gender, if you were to use a boolean field, then you can do..

```
name_a = some_db_query_for_name
if name_a.gender = true:
    a = "she"
else:
    a = "he"
```

then in your templates just reference

```
@name_a likes @name_b, @a is ...
```

Im sorry its not ruby/rails code, but I saw the question and this seemed the best way to approach it.